# Blogging Software for Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, open-source, blogs

I have a good bit of experience with Google App Engine but I wanted to see if there is any code already out there for a solid blogging site running on Google App Engine.

I have seen a few decent options and this question was asked 3 years ago:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804368/blogging-system-which-runs-on-the-google-app-engine but a number of those options are outdated and are not longer kept up.

Comment: This is not a software recommendation site or link locator. Google and Bing both specialize in providing links for things you're searching for, and they're both pretty effectivee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are among the best I found: [bloog](http://bloog.billkatz.com/), [project-picky](http://code.google.com/p/project-picky/), [joey-blog](https://github.com/joeyb/joeyb-blog).